# Attempting to array table data attr contents using each

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I am trying to get the contents of a table to an array, where each `tr` has html5 custom data attributes, and those are the values inserted to the array, where rows are respective of the array.

I have tried the following:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/vG36j/1/)

```
var data = Array();

$("table tr").each(function(i, v){
    data[i] = Array();
    $(this).data().each(function(ii, vv){
        data[i][ii] = $(this).text();
    }); 
});

alert(data);
```

This however does not work.

Comment: So many mistakes: You can't call `data()` with no arguments, you have to supply the attribute name. It returns a string, not an array. `.text()` only works on jQuery objects for DOM elements, not ordinary objects.

Comment: @Barmar Actually you can call `data()` with no arguments, [here is the documentation on it](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data)

Comment: Also, you can't initialise an array with `Array()` its either `new Array()` or `[]`, the latter being preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question now, the following code gets the values from the data attributes on the trs and adds them to an array.

```
var data = [];

$("table tr").each(function (i, v) {
    data[i] = [];
    var count = 0;
    var item = $(this).data();
    for(var propertyName in item) {
       data[i][count] = item[propertyName];
       count++;
   }
});
console.log(data);
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/vG36j/13/

Comment: When looping with `for-in` you should test `hasOwnProperty` to skip over inherited properties.

Comment: Agreed, but the object is `$(this).data()`, so i can't see how it will inherit any properties?

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to achieve. I have about 6 different ways i've tried it, but this is the exact thing i was aiming for. thanks

Comment: My mistake, when I was looking at it in my console I thought I saw other properties.

Comment: Note that this solution just shows the data values without any names. And the order of them is totally unpredictable.

Comment: @Barmar also correct, it could be expanded depending on requirements to easily show this, however. Personally I'd probably store an object with a key value pair rather than just the values if it was me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an object, not an array. Here's how you should probably go about it:

```
var data = [];

$("table tr").each(function(i, v){
    data[i] = {};
    $.each($(this).data(), function(ii, vv) {
        data[i][ii] = vv;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`data()` returns an object, not an array, so you can't iterate over it with the `each()` method. You could loop over it using `$.each`, but there's no need to do that -- you can simply put the whole object directly into `data[i]`.

```
var data = [];

$("table tr").each(function(i, v){
    data[i] = $(this).data(); 
});

console.log(data);
```

I used `console.log()` at the end because `alert()` doesn't show the contents of objects.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/vG36j/11/)

Comment: `.data()` returns an object which you can enumerate over to pull the properties from.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? `.data().each()` doesn't work with an object, it only works with an array. `$.each($(this).data(), ...)` would work.